# How to get custom option on client from ISC DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, freebsd, isc-dhcp, dhcp-option

Over ISC-DHCP server I wanted to define a custom DHCP Option, for which I am using below config

```
option imagefile code 224 = ip-address;

subnet 192.168.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.29.1 192.168.29.244;
 option imagefile 192.168.29.113;
}
```

I am able to restart DHCP server after above configuration.

However on client I am not able to grab this option. I am expecting to have this information in /var/db/dhclient.leases.em0

I am having a freebsd client.

I also tried to define below config in dhclinet (onclient side )

```
#option imagefile code 224 = ip-address ;
interface "em0" {
  option imagefile code 224 = ip-address;
  request imagefile;
}
```

However my service did not get start correctly .i.e.

```
Starting dhclient.
/etc/dhclient.conf line 12: expecting a statement.
  option 
  ^
/etc/dhclient.conf line 13: semicolon expected.
  request 
  ^
DHCPREQUEST on em0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK from 192.168.29.113
bound to 192.168.29.234 -- renewal in 17669 seconds.
```

Kindly help with correct dhclient configuration or if I need to change something on isc-dhcp server to automatically get this custom option on client without defining any config on client

Comment: In server, try `option option-224 "192.168.29.113";` (see [dhcp-options](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dhcp-options&sektion=5&manpath=freebsd-release-ports))

Comment: @VladimirBotka , I tried that on server however ISC-DHCP server did not restart complaining about syntax.
   for custom option definition on server I have followed this 
    (https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcp-options#DEFINING%20NEW%20OPTIONS) 

If i try same on dhcp client it also saying syntax errors.

Comment: so in client if I try below in /etc/dhclient.conf 

request option-224;

I get below value in lease file
lease {
interface "em0";
....
....
option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.29.113;
option option-224 "http://testing.com";
.....
....
}


dhcp server config is like


option url code 224 = string;
subnet 192.168.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.29.1 192.168.29.244;
#option www-server 192.168.29.113;
option url "http://testing.com";
}

however yet its not getting on name.